# mongoose update object in array with a specific key

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

so I have this mongoose schema:

```
schema = mongoose.Schema({
    identifier: Number,
    shopItems: [{
         identifier: Number,
         price: Number
    }]
});
```

now I know how to push new items to this collections shopItems array with`{ $push { shopItems { identifier: id, price: price } }`.

But now I want to update an item in the shopItems array with a specific identifier value, is that possible?

I was thinking that this would work: `{ $push { "shopItems.identifier": myVal, price: newPrice } }` but it didnt, so I am really lost.

Comment: Do you have a old value for a `identifier` to identify its position in `shopItems` array ? If yes you can use positional operator to update the `identifier` at that position with new element. Something like find and replace in array.     `db.collection_name.update({"shopItems.identifier": id}, {"$set":{"shopItems.$":{identifier:myVal, price: newPrice }}})`

Comment: @Veeram yes I do have a value for the identifier, I want to find the item in the array with the correct identifier and update its prices.

Comment: Use this if you only like to update prices.  `db.collection_name.update({"shopItems.identifier": myVal}, {"$set":{"shopItems.$.price: newPrice }})`

Comment: @Veeram thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows:

```
db.collection.update({'shopItems.identifier' : myVal }, { $set : { 'shopItems.$.price' : newPrice}});
```

Comment: It is not working for me. I am getting Invalid BSON field name.

Comment: how do i do for multiple object?